# Syncfusion controls render in the designer, but not in browser

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, syncfusion

I just added Syncfusion (Version=15.4460.0.17) to an existing site.  I can view all Syncfusion controls in my VS designer, but only the Syncfusion text boxes show up when you try to view the page in a browser.

The dll's, css files, and js files are all where they need to be.  Since some controls show up, and others don't I feel like a java script or css isn't being reference correctly.

Here's a basic page that doesn't display a grid.  I've got a functional datasource on the page.  It does populate and render the native asp .net gridview.

> Here is the .aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SF.aspx.vb" Inherits="SF" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web" tagprefix="ej" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models" tagprefix="ej" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ej/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ej/ej.webform.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/ej/web/ej.widgets.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/ej/web/default-theme/ej.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />        
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        1<ej:Grid ID="Grid1" runat="server" CssClass="" DataSourceCachingMode="None" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableLoadOnDemand="False" MinWidth="0">
        </ej:Grid>
        <br />
        2<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT top 5 [UserID], [Name], [Email], [Active] FROM [Users]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Here's what's in the Web.config:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Pivot, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.PivotAnalysis.Base, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.XlsIO.base, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
    <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.ReportViewer, Version=15.4460.0.17, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

> Here are the actual rendered HTML results from Andrew Morton's 2nd suggestion.

```
1<div id="MyGrid1" data-role="ejgrid" data-ej-datasource='ej.dataSources.MyGrid1.data0' data-ej-cssclass='' data-ej-uniqueId=MyGrid1 data-ej-clientId=MyGrid1 ></div><script>ej.createObject("ej.dataSources.MyGrid1",{"data0":ej.isJSON([{"RepID":1,"Name":"Paul","Email":"paul@email.com","Active":"Yes"},{"RepID":2,"Name":"Tom","Email":"Tom@email.com","Active":"No"},{"RepID":4,"Name":"Larry","Email":"Larry@email.com","Active":"No"},{"RepID":5,"Name":"Mack","Email":"mackemail.com","Active":"No"},{"RepID":6,"Name":"Gary","Email":"gary@email.com","Active":"No"}])});</script><span id="MyGrid1"></span>
            <br />
            2<br /><div>
        <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">RepID</th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Email</th><th scope="col">Active</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1</td><td>Paul</td><td>paul@email.com</td><td>Yes</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>2</td><td>Tom</td><td>tom@email.com</td><td>No</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>4</td><td>Larry</td><td>larry@email.com</td><td>No</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>5</td><td>Mack</td><td>mack@email.com</td><td>No</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>6</td><td>Gary</td><td>gary@email.com</td><td>No</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you aware that your browser has developer tools, invoked by pressing F12, which will show you network activity and if any files didn't get loaded (e.g. with a 404 status)?

Comment: I was not aware of that.  I used the F12 tool to find a couple of files that didn't get loaded, and resolved those issues.  I'm still experiencing the same issue though.

Comment: The next step is to check the *rendered* HTML for validity. Ctrl-U should get you a page of that which you can then submit to the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). And then in the F12 tools, look at the Console section to see if any JavaScript errors are being reported.

Comment: I did this, and didn't uncover any additional errors.  In the rendered HTML view, I can see that it actually does create the Syncfusion grid.  It has a div with some Syncfusion tags in it, AND it has the data for the 5 records which are returned from the datasource. i added a snip it from results to the original post.

Comment: i m facing the same problem with my existing project. it was working earlier and suddenly it stopped and displaying only text box. however when i call JavaScript function $('#controlid').ejDateTimePicker() it appears